# Bash: Use flags without inserting arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm working on a script that runs spotifyd and spotify-tui, one after the other. I want to add an option (we'll call that `-k`) that, when used, automatically kills spotifyd's daemon once spotify-tui's process is killed. I've done all my research, and nothing useful has come up.

Here is my code so far:

```
spotify () { 
  # initiate spotifyd
  if [[ -z $(ps -e | grep spotifyd) ]]; then
    spotifyd --config-path ~/.config/spotifyd.conf
  fi

  # start spotify-tui
  spt
    
  # kill spotifyd
  # don't be alarmed, this will only run once spotify-tui exits and the user wants spotifyd to die
  while getopts k: option
  do
  case "${option}" in
  k)
    killall spotifyd
    exit
    ;;
  esac
  done
}
```

Using this in practice causes Bash to yell at me:

```
spotify:11: argument expected after -k option
```

This error never appears if `-k` is never used. Could I get some help on how to allow the flag to be sent through without needing any extra parameters?

Comment: `getopts` expecting an argument for option `-k` because of the `:` (also, based on the error message, it looks like you're actually using zsh rather than bash here?)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `getopts k:`, with the colon after `k`, you're telling `getopts` that `-k` expects an argument. [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-getopts):

> `getopts optstring name [args]`
>
> `getopts` is used by shell scripts to parse positional parameters. *optstring* contains the option characters to be recognized; **if a character is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument**, which should be separated from it by whitespace.

Use just `getopts k`. Or if that's really the only command line argument you ever expect, you don't need `getopts` at all, just something like `if [ "$1" = -k ]; then ... fi`, though in both cases, you might want to add a branch to print an error for unknown options.